# How to create multiple tables for authentication in django

Tags: django, authentication, multiple-users

There is anyway to create two user tables that can be authenticated in django one table will be used to register normal users and other admins but that can not be related with  django.contrib.auth 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not rational to treat different between users and admins by putting them in two separated tables. You can give different permissions to different users and treat them due to which resources they must access. for more information check [django permissions documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But  I'm trying to do a test, It is just to know if is possible to have more than one table for authentication